# Decoding base64 image string to an image in Unity

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, base64

I'm using the following code encode an image from python end,

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5558")

frame = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(buffer)
socket.send_string("output", zmq.SNDMORE)
socket.send_pyobj(encoded_string)
```

Eventually, I'm using the following code to decrypt it in Unity end.

```
void Start()
{
    AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
    NetMQConfig.ManualTerminationTakeOver();
    NetMQConfig.ContextCreate(false);
    string topic = "output";
    subSocket = new SubscriberSocket();
    
    var timeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); //1sec
    string subport;
    
    subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
    subSocket.Connect("tcp://localhost:5558");
    subSocket.Subscribe(topic);
    bool is_connected =  subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(timeout, out subport);
    
    Debug.Log(is_connected);

    myTexture = new Texture2D(640, 480, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
        
    string base64string = subSocket.ReceiveFrameString();
    Debug.Log(base64string.Length);
   
    
    if (base64string.Length > 100)
    {
        byte[] imgBytes = Convert. FromBase64String(base64string);

        
        myTexture.LoadRawTextureData(imgBytes);
        myTexture.Apply();

        rawImg.texture = myTexture;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it throws the following error,

> FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
> contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
> an illegal character among the padding characters.

what am I missing?

Comment: Remember that `b64encode` doesn't change the buffer in place.  It returns a new string, as in: `b64result = base64.b64encode(buffer)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts could you please explain a bit?

Comment: You are calling `base64.b64encode(buffer)`.  If that's really all you have, then the encoder will happily base64-encode all the bytes in the buffer, then return the encoded result to you, which you promptly throw on the floor.  The data in `buffer` will not be changed.  You need to catch the return value in a new (or the same) variable, as I have done above.  It's like calling `math.sqrt(64)`.  That computes a result, but unless you save the return value, the result will evaporate.

Comment: it is still throwing the same error even after the segregation as `encoded_string = base64.b64encode(buffer))`

Comment: OK, but did you change things to send "encoded_string" to the client, or are you still sending "buffer"?

Comment: I have also change the client to `encoded_string`

Comment: Then why don't you update the question to show us what your code looks like now, including the code that sends the string?

Comment: Please add more context of how exactly you send the data in python and how exactly your complete receiver looks like in Unity

Comment: @derHugo please check the updated code

Comment: Just in general, do you think it is a good idea to receive data and create a new texture **every frame**?

Comment: @derHugo definitely not.. I will move it to the start method

Comment: @derHugo any idea? :)

Comment: Can you add what `Debug.Log(base64string);` prints? It should only contain the characters mentioned in [`FromBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you could try sending a very small image through the channel (encode, transfer, receive) and log-print what was received on the other end.

**My suspicions**:

- Somehow you're not converting to base-64
- You end up sending too many bytes, or unnecessary bytes (null-termination character?)
- Receiving the image content in a manner that adds CR or LF at the end (such as 'HTTP Response' body)

More information is needed to provide a better answer...